# Is there a tool or web service for converting emails to url calls?

Tags: web-services, email, url

I want to have a URL of my server called as soon as a new email arrives. Does anyone know a tool likes this? The email address does not need to be my domain.

My dream would be a service that works like this:

- Lets assume the service is called "mail2url.com"
- Register a custom address e.g. qoiasdajk18@mail2url.com (so its not guessable)
- Tell the service to call http://myserver.com/myscript.php when an new email arrives

(I know I could do this by myself, but I need it very fast and reliable)

Thanks,
Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CloudMailin.com](http://cloudmailin.com). It does exactly what you are asking for. It was designed to be hugely scalable and stable and you can easily use your own domain too like you asked.